# clearing orphaned inode HELP PLEASE!

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Clearing orphaned Inode 26615 etc. I get this error while trying to boot it up, After it boots up to the desktop i cant see my mouse or use the keyboard I am currently running ubuntu 16.04.I just installed intel graphic drivers and it asked me to reboot the machine and so did i, just after that i get this problem.

Comment: Can you use the key combination `CTRL+ALT+F2` to move to a non-graphical, text based tty? You can use `CTRL+ALT+F7` if it works to return to your desktop environment.

Comment: The supposed error isn't an error, just a message. However, it suggests that you may have problems in the drive where Ubuntu is installed. It has nothing to do with the issue you reported. Please edit your question and post hardware specs, especially graphics, because this most likely is related to graphics drivers.

Comment: I cannot use the Keyboard its literally off for some reason.. i just installed intel graphics and it ask me to reboot the machine, and i did so just after it rebooted i got this thing. I cannot see the mouse or use it and i cant use the keyboard.

Comment: Are you able to use your keyboard to enter the BIOS? Have you tried plugging your keyboard into a different port?

Comment: Yes i did try but won't work no changes are made.

Comment: Does it work to access the BIOS? That was the question and the purpose of it is to determine whether or not the keyboard works *outside* the OS. It's just a test and not intended to solve anything. And again, please post hardware specs.

Comment: Yes the mouse and keyboard work on bios but as soon as i open ubuntu the screen is frozen no mouse shown or keyboard working.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove the package(s) you just installed using a live session.

1. You'll need another computer to make a bootable USB stick on [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or [Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
2. Boot into your USB, and find your Ubuntu root parition(`ext4`with `LABEL="root"`, or no label): 
   `sudo blkid | grep ext4`
3. Mount your Ubuntu root partition:
   `sudo mount /dev/sda[?] /mnt/`
4. Change root:
   `sudo chroot /mnt/`
5. Remove the intel package:
   `apt-get remove --purge [intel-package-name]`
6. Umount and restart: 
   `exit` 
   `sudo umount /mnt/ && sudo reboot`